# Printing out exact character value when using array in C programming

Tags: arrays

I enter two names in this case 'Jack' and 'Sara' and when i want to printout 
'Jack' and 'Sara', This only prints out the last name which is sara im just wonderig how can i solve this problem even i wanna use more names here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
        char name[20];
        int i;

        printf("\n\n");

        for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
                printf("Person.%d  FristName: ", i);
                scanf(" %s", name);
        }

        printf("\n\nHi %s \n", name);
        printf("Hi %s \n", name);

        return 0;
}
```

And here is the Output:

Hi Sara

Hi Sara

Comment: Because you're printing "Hi, [name]" outside of the loop so it prints whatever the last entered name is. Move your print statement inside the loop.

Comment: Yea but i want to print out all names together at the end not one by one ! what should i do in this case?

Comment: Then you would need to store the names in an array.